# C - What is the most efficient way to allocate big matrices for computations (based on time efficiency when computing)?

Tags: c

I intend to do several matrix computations (matrix * vector, system of linear equations and matrix * matrix). Firstly I prepared code using basic on-stack alocation (which resulted in stack overflow) and changed it to dynamically allocated ones (as seen in the first snipped, I used "double vectors" to simulate the indexing). Then I found that using simpler 1D allocation lends faster computations due to easier caching and less pointer navigation.

The results were unhelpfull. First approach made first two operations faster but the third one took ages (>1s, 6s, 140s). Second approach sped up the matrix*matrix part but slowed everything else (>1s, 65s, 114s).

So, what is the most efficient way to allocate memory for big matrices that lends fastest computation times?
(I ommited the part about filling Af with numbers due to examples being already code-heavy)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define n 2000
#define n2 n*n

int main()
{
    double** A = (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    double* Af = (double*)calloc(n2, sizeof(double));

    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            A[j][i] = Af[temp];
            temp++;
        }
    }

    double* x = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = i + 1;
    }

    start = clock();
    double* b = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            {
                b[i] += A[i][k] * x[k];
            }
        }
    }

    end = clock();
    seconds = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("first = %f\n s", seconds);
    free(Af);

    start = clock();
    double temp2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (A[i][i] == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (j == i)
                    continue;
                if (A[j][i] != 0 && A[i][j] != 0)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                    {
                        temp2 = A[j][k];
                        A[j][k] = A[i][k];
                        A[i][k] = temp2;
                    }
                    temp2 = b[j];
                    b[j] = b[i];
                    b[i] = temp2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (A[i][i] == 0)
        {
            return 123;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            double ratio = A[j][i] / A[i][i];
            for (int k = i; k < n; k++)
            {
                A[j][k] -= ratio * A[i][k];
            }
            b[j] -= ratio * b[i];
        }
    }

    x[n - 1] = b[n - 1] / A[n - 1][n - 1];

    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        x[i] = b[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            x[i] = x[i] - A[i][j] * x[j];
        }
        x[i] = x[i] / A[i][i];
    }

    end = clock();
    seconds = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("second = %f\n s", seconds);

    free(x);
    free(b);

    start = clock();
    double** Asqr = (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Asqr[i] = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            {
                Asqr[i][j] += A[i][k] * A[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    end = clock();
    seconds = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("second = %f\n s", seconds);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
       free (A[i]);
       free (Asqrt[i]);
    }
    free (A);
    free (Asqrt);
}
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define n 2000
#define n2 n*n

int main()
{
    double* Af = (double*)calloc(n2, sizeof(double));

    int temp = 0;

    double* x = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = i + 1.0;
    }

    start = clock();
    double* b = (double*)calloc(n, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            {
                b[i + n * j] += Af[i + n * k] * x[k + n * j];
            }
        }
    }

    end = clock();
    seconds = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("first = %f\n s", seconds);


    start = clock();
    double temp2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (Af[i + n * i] == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (j == i)
                    continue;
                if (Af[j + n * i] != 0 && Af[i + n * j] != 0)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                    {
                        temp2 = Af[j + n * k];
                        Af[j + n * k] = Af[i + n * k];
                        Af[i + n * k] = temp2;
                    }
                    temp2 = b[j];
                    b[j] = b[i];
                    b[i] = temp2;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (Af[i + n * i] == 0)
        {
            return 123;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            double ratio = Af[j + n * i] / Af[i + n * i];
            for (int k = i; k < n; k++)
            {
                Af[j + n * k] -= ratio * Af[i + n * k];
            }
            b[j] -= ratio * b[i];
        }
    }

    x[n - 1] = b[n - 1] / Af[(n-1) + n * (n-1)];

    for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        x[i] = b[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            x[i] = x[i] - Af[i + n * j] * x[j];
        }
        x[i] = x[i] / Af[i + n * i];
    }

    end = clock();
    seconds = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("sysOfLinEqSolutionTime = %f\n s", seconds);
    free(x);
    free(b);

    start = clock();
    double* Asqr = (double*)calloc(n2, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k)
            {
                Asqr[i + n * j] += Af[i + n * k] * Af[k + n * j];
            }
        }
    }

    end = clock();
    seconds = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("matrixSquareTime = %f\n s", seconds);
    free(Af);
    free(Asqr);
```

Comment: have you considered to use a pre-existing library for this? maxtrix operations are a field where optimizations really make a difference. BLAS is one example.

Comment: @JörgBeyer I simultaneously work with CBLAS/LAPCKE. I just hoped to have somewhat reliable comparison to actually justify using it.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of columns (such as `n`), then you can use a single-allocation to create an nxn block of memory to hold your "matrix" (2D array), e.g. `double (*matrix)[n] = malloc (n * sizeof *matrix);` You can then address as normal (e.g. `matrix[i][j]`). This is much more time efficient than allocating `n`-pointers and then `n`-`n * sizeof(double)` blocks of memory and assigning each to your pointers in succession. (and you have a contiguous block of memory allowing a single `free()`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin and that would be faster even that the second approach (singular block with calloc)? Also worth noting that I need those to start as zeros (malloc is also used when I don't) so I guess that time of zeroing the memory would also need to be factored.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: @CostantinoGrana atm Win32 Release (so I think yes).

Comment: @Daractive you can use `calloc` to zero the block, `double (*matrix)[n] = calloc (n, sizeof *matrix);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin excuse me if I'm missing something but wouldn't such approach equate to my third take (second code sample)? Or is this way for some reason better (I'm sorta confused)?

Comment: Are you worried about the performance of your code, or your code is fine and the only problem is the memory allocation? Because your way of performing matrix multiplication is extremely slow and probably you should instrument your code to measure the time spent in the allocation and that spent in the actual computation.

Comment: If we are looking at the same thing, your 3rd use of `calloc` only allocates for a block of `n` values, not a block of `n x n` values.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin for the ones that should be n x n it does alocate this much (with x and b being vectors it would be only Af) but as a single continuous block that gets the navigated as a 2D matrix (or at least that's what I intended to do) to avoid nesting vectors.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana I'm looking for "best of the worst". I want to find the fastest way to do this with basic C utilities so I have some kind of comparison for when I include matrix-intended libraries without making the plain C one obviously bloated.

Comment: Is `n` fixed [constant]? You can do `calloc` in `main`. Then, put all calculations in functions that have a signature like: `void docalc(double Af[n][n]) { Af[10][13] = 23; }` If _not_ fixed, do: `void dodyn(int ny,int nx,double Af[ny][nx]) { ... }` This allows you to still treat it like a normal array in the subfunction _without_ having to resort to indirect pointers.

Comment: BTW, as others have mentioned, your benchmarking is broken. Put the allocations (e.g. `calloc/free`) _outside_ of the `start = clock(); ... stop = clock();` window. And, you should put the tests in separate functions, so you can run the tests several times each [and take the best/minimum time]. This eliminates variations in what the system is doing elsewhere (i.e. being timesliced away in the middle of a test) and smoothes out the effects of memory caching.